# black list subdomain url extensions

Tags: email, plesk, blacklist

Spammers use loop holes to kill us with spam and here is the loop hole in question in an example
email@abcd.abc.us
Or
email@abcd.abc.com
Spammers know we can block spam coming from any obscure domains such as .date .download etc and they also know we cannot block entire domains that are massively used by the general populations such as .com and .us
So they use subdomains as a loop hole because the spammers know we will not block .us or .com entirely

Below you will see domains and other extensions that spammers use that I have blacklisted. 
 [Plesk Black List Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q00U9.png)
In Pleask > Tools & Settings > Mail Server Settings > Black List > Add Addresses. I want to black list all sub directory domains such as *.*.us but i cannot because
Separate multiple addresses with a new line, a white space, a tab, a comma, or a semicolon. There must be no non-ASCII characters to the left of the @ sign. Addresses can contain "*" and "?" wildcards (for example, *@domain.com, user?@*.com). Non-ASCII parts of domain names must not contain wildcards. I do not want to block domains such as .us just the all the sub domains directory domains. I find that SPAM comes form popular domains with different sub domains to make it hard to blacklist. Please add this rule ASAP. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add `*.gdn` and `*.xyz` -  Can you add `*.abc.com`, which should work?

Comment: yes you can add *.abc.com but the problem is that abc changes as the spammers are very smart and the directories under the sub domain change as they please and this is the loop hole. I wish the  www internet protocol will allow us to black list domains that use sub domains or sub directories in their emails like this *.*.com

Comment: Maybe you can do `*.???.com`, `*.????.com`, `*.????.com` just keep repeating that pattern out.

Comment: I was able to find a friend that had a .us email address and tested out the patters you gave me above. I was able to receive all incoming emails from a .us email. Now to wait to see if we were able to block the spam directories with the sub domains. Ill let you guys know. Thanks again, Jesse

Comment: Well it seem that the fix did not work. I was inundated by spam that we targeted. I guess we have to wait till the protocols change and allow Plesk to give us more abilities on what to block... Right?

Comment: Here are some examples of the spam Nutritionand--Healing@yelad.in.net and PSFiltration--Straw@trola.in.net I wanted to share these to make sure i am describing them correctly. I wish i could just blacklist any emails coming in with subdomains just like these examples.

Comment: seems they now allow, *@*.*.us
Lets see if this will help cut down on spam that uses this technique.